# manpages for my kindle?

Tags: man, hypertext

I'd like to read unix manpages on my kindle. I know I can just redirect the man output to a file and give it a .txt extension. But is there a convenient way to convert them *en masse* to a format with proper cross-references?

Edit: An apology for my behavior in this question. I told pat that I would accept the comment if submitted as an answer, and then better answers came and I did not keep my promise (Sorry). I enthusiastically accepted Caleb's answer that produces html versions of the manpages; and then some time later when I actually tried transferring the files to the kindle, I discovered that the kindle would not display html files; and I switched acceptance without explanation (Sorry). The kindle appears to require .txt or .pdf (or one of the various *real* eBook formats). I hope I have explained myself.

Also, I didn't have a realistic understanding of how many, many manpages there are with a Debian Linux distribution, and so Caleb's comment about selecting a "Best Of" collection appears to be the best idea. But I don't really have the inclination to try to do this myself (which is a prerequisite for asking questions on StackExchange sites), so I'm not comfortable asking how to select the "Best Of", even though it really is necessary practically in order to do this.

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/21903/man-pages-offline-for-e-reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert every man page to pdf I did `man -k . > temp`.  I created a temp file and a script named `file.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
    to_pdf=$(which ps2pdf)
    if [ -z "$to_pdf" ] ; then
    to_pdf=$(which pstopdf)
    fi
    name="$1"
    case "$to_pdf"  in
        *pstopdf) man -t "$name" | "$to_pdf" -i -o "$fname.pdf" ;;
        *ps2pdf)  man -t "$name" | "$to_pdf" - "$name.pdf" ;;
        *)        man -t "$name" > "$fname.ps"
    esac
    exit $?
fi
echo "Wrong number of parameters"
exit 1
```

I wrote a python file `pythonfile.py`

```
import os
f=open("temp","r")
for i in f:
    c="bash file.sh "+str(i)
    os.system(c)`
```

Then I did

```
python pythonfile.py
```

This will create a pdf for every man page separately inside your working directory.

Answer (score 7):

To dump all the sections of all the man pages on your system to html you could try something like this from a blank directory:

```
IFS=\.
find /usr/share/man/man* -type f -exec basename {} .gz \; |
    while read page section; do
        man -Thtml $section $page > $page.$section.html
    done
```

Comment: Gee, it sure takes a `while`, don't it? :)

Comment: @luserdroog: Yes indeed it does. You're the one that asked to convert every unix man page on your system _en masse_! If what you really want is a "best of" collection to browse in your spare time, a different approach is probably in order.